# user-defined function as a parameter passed to cpp class constructor

Tags: c++

i want to have a class member which is a pointer to undefined typical function .
the function must be performed by user. the user must pass the function as a parameter to class constructor.
the function is called in the scope of class methodes.
can i do these tasks like this ?

```
class MyClss
{
    private:    
    bool (*f)();

    public:
    MyClss(bool (*fp)());
    void MyMethod();
}

MyClss::MyClss(bool (*fp)())
{
    f = fp;
}

void MyClss::MyMethod()
{
    // do tasks
    if(f())
    {
        // do tasks
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try? Did it fail? There's nothing *wrong* with the code you show, other than a missing semi-colon.

Comment: Might want to consider [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: i would suggest to use <functional> and use std::function<bool()> as parameter

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given will works fine. See the code below it is the same but using `std::function` from `<functional>` header file.

```
#include <functional>

// The function prototype.
typedef std::function<bool()> MyFunction;

class MyClss
{
    private:    
    MyFunction f;

    public:
    MyClss(MyFunction fp);
    void MyMethod();
};

MyClss::MyClss(MyFunction fp)
{
    f = fp;
}

void MyMethod()
{
    // do tasks
    if(f())
    {
        // do tasks
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [using std is bad practive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)